# Cannot set destination table in jobs with DML statements problem in Big query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata, portfolio

BIGQUERY
I am trying to merge 12 tables into one master table but it won't let me set it permanently as the new result.it runs the query fine when it is set as temporary result but when I try to select the option 'Set a destination table for query results." in query settings I get this message 'Cannot set destination table in jobs with DML statements'

the query I am running is
INSERT INTO
`perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.All_12months`
SELECT
*
FROM
`perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.01_2023`
UNION ALL
SELECT
*
FROM
`perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.02_2023`
UNION ALL
SELECT
*
FROM
`perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.03_2022`
UNION ALL
SELECT
*
FROM
`perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.04_2022`
UNION ALL
SELECT
*
FROM
`perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.05_2022`
UNION ALL
SELECT
*
FROM
`perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.06_2022`
UNION ALL
SELECT
*
FROM
`perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.07_2022`
UNION ALL
SELECT
*
FROM
`perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.08_2022`
UNION ALL
SELECT
*
FROM
`perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.09_2022`
UNION ALL
SELECT
*
FROM
`perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.10_2022`
UNION ALL
SELECT
*
FROM
`perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.11_2022`
UNION ALL
SELECT
*
FROM
`perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.12

I have tried to run the query in different formats and settings but I dont know what the problem is. I am new to sql query and I am doing this for a project on my portfolio.

EDIT:Is there another way I can merge all the tables together without having to write a query?

Comment: Did you try to put your union in a `with` and then to use this with in your insert into?

Comment: can you give me an example on how I should write the query?

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
INSERT INTO `perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.All_12months` 
with DATA_UNION as (
SELECT * FROM `perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.01_2023` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.02_2023` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.03_2022` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.04_2022` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.05_2022` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.06_2022` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.07_2022` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.08_2022` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.09_2022` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.10_2022` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.11_2022` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `perfect-victor-384401.Bike_project_coursra.12`) 
select * from DATA_UNION
```

Comment: I am getting an error message that says Syntax error: "Unclosed identifier literal at [1:13]"

Comment: Yes, backquote are missing. I updated the content.